# add timestamp to pdf with itext MakeSignature.signDeferred

Tags: itext

I'm using itext MakeSignature.signDeferred to add signature to pdf.
I use deferred signig because i use external signature container.
How is possible to add timestamp in this case, the method not support tsaclient parameter like signDetached
   MakeSignature.signDetached(sap, externalDigest, externalSignature, chain, crlList, ocspClient, **tsaClient**, estimatedSize, sigtype);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method doesn't support a tsaclient for obvious reasons: you use external signature functionality to create the signature bytes. These bytes may not be altered, but need to be inserted into the PDF "as-is". This means that it's up to your external signature container to support timestamps. If it doesn't, you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. Any example how to do it, my external signature container only return the digital signature bytearray

Comment: As I don't know which external signature functionality you're using, it is impossible to provide an example. Please ask the persons responsible for writing your external signature functionality for an example.